# Static analysis for call-graph generation in C programs

Tags: c, call-graph

I found plenty of programs such as `Doxygen` or `gprof` that can do the job using external visualization tools like `graphviz`.

Unfortunately these programs requires lots of initial configuration where I am only interested to know the call-stack of the functions that use `malloc`.

The project is huge, hundred of files and somewhere a `main` function.

My current solution which will take me some time is to write a Perl/Python script that:

1. Search for `malloc\s*(.*?)` calls.
2. Retrieve the name of the parent function
3. Search where this parent function is called
4. goto 2

Is there some utilities that can help me in here?

The project is on Microsoft VisualStudio 2010 and generate dlls as an API for an embedded device. The use of external libraries is not very large. We use common libraries such as ftdi or wdapi910

Comment: What kind of project is it? What operating system? What compiler? What source code size? What external libraries?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I edited my  question

Comment: OK, you've find a malloc call in the middle of "foo".  What, exactly, is the name of the "parent" function, and how will you find it?   Esp. if there are function pointers?  I don't think your "current solution" will get you very much.

Comment: Well, so I doubt it too :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `malloc` related bugs, the [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) tool is very useful (at runtime, when testing).

Your quest cannot be satisfied by purely textual inspection of source code (e.g. because `malloc` might be called from many inlined functions or macros, and because it even could be `#define`-d to something else, or called thru function pointers, or in functions from external libraries: even `fopen` or `fprintf` may call `malloc`). Actually it can be proven equivalent to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Also, the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) is only known at runtime, and it is dynamically changing. It has no sense at compile time. The compiler only organize call frames.

You need a tool which works inside the compiler, on internal representations of the compiler, so you need some more sophisticated [static program analyzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis), and even that will give you approximate results.

You could use [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (a plugin and domain specific language to customize the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, that I am developing as free software) since it works on GCC internal representations. The example of `findgimple` mode in the [tutorial about using MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/tutousemelt.html) is quite close to your question, but you could customize GCC with your own MELT extension (or ask someone to do that).

PS. `valgrind` & MELT are mostly available on Linux and POSIX systems. You might try hard to find costly equivalents in the Microsoft ecosystem.

Comment: I am more interested by the `static` `call-stack` in which I mean the call-tree from the entry function `main()` down to all the leafs. I guess that even static functions can be parsed if we care to run the pre processor right before starting the analysis. Am I wrong.

Comment: As soon as your program have function pointers, your quest is statically undecidable (can be proven equivalent to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)). The call graph cannot be known (only overapproximated)